# Is this sar/sysstat cron job formatted correctly?

Tags: cron, sar, sysstat

I want it to give me all the sar/sadc options, interrupts,disk,etc.. every 10 seconds starting at noon for the entire hour.  On the second line I want to capture the info in /proc/interrupts every minute for the hour of noon in a log file.  Please verify the syntax.

```
* 12 * * *  root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S XALL 10 360
*/1 12 * * *  root cat /proc/interrupts >> /root/proc_int.log && date >> /root/proc_int.log
```

Comment: If I understood correctly your first line should be something like `0 12 * * * command`. In actual state it will run sa1 command every minute for an hour. You will get 60 mails. Second line looks good for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sa1` command collects and stores binary data in system activity data file. The command is a kind of shell wrapper of `sadc` command and it accepts all its parameters. So check the `sadc` man page for details.

The first line above is correct as `XALL`  means to collect all available system activities. The collection will run for 1 hour (10 * 360s = 3600s = 1h) as required. The second line is all right as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think your entry is awesome.  It collects over the full interval vs. 1 second I see everywhere else.  Because, as I (Charles Stepp) have [commented](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/#comment-2400329) on the "[10 Useful Sar (Sysstat) Examples for UNIX / Linux Performance Monitoring](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/)" article on the web site "[The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/)":

> In the crontab entry, you should not be limiting the interval to 1
>   second. Sar uses the same system resources no matter how long the
>   interval is. It reads kernel values, sleeps, reads the values again
>   and records/prints the difference value. 1 second, 10 seconds, 1200
>   seconds are the same as far as sar’s resource usage. 99.99% of sar’s
>   usage is sleep, which is what the kernel does anyway when it’s not
>   doing anything. Note below that the first sar sample of only a second
>   showed an average cpu of 3%. The longer samples, averaging over a
>   longer period, show that 6% is probably more of an accurate average,
>   at this time. The web pages I’ve seen so far feed each other with this
>   1 second sample thing, almost like someone is afraid sar might bog the
>   system down. It won’t. The same two sets of kernel reads happens no
>   matter what the interval is:

```
time sar 1 1; time sar 10 1; time sar 100 1
Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 (blahblah) 10/07/14
12:04:51 CPU %user %nice %system %iowait %steal %idle
12:04:52 all 3.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 96.25
Average: all 3.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 96.25
sar 1 1 0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.005 total
Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 (blahblah) 10/07/14
12:04:52 CPU %user %nice %system %iowait %steal %idle
12:05:02 all 6.21 0.00 0.93 0.20 0.00 92.67
Average: all 6.21 0.00 0.93 0.20 0.00 92.67
sar 10 1 0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.005 total
Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 (blahblah) 10/07/14
12:05:02 CPU %user %nice %system %iowait %steal %idle
12:06:42 all 6.32 0.00 0.97 0.24 0.00 92.47
Average: all 6.32 0.00 0.97 0.24 0.00 92.47
sar 100 1 0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1:40.01 total
```

> From the man page example it shows each hour having 3 20 minute
>   samples. This provides accurate averaging and small sa## files. A 1
>   second interval each 10 minutes is 1/600th of the information
>   available.

```
EXAMPLES
To create a daily record of sar activities, place the following entry
in your root or adm crontab file:
0 8-18 * * 1-5 /usr/lib/sa/sa1 1200 3 &"
```

Comment: Consider cleaning up this formatting, it's quite difficult to read at the moment.